# Disable select button while selecting location of anonymous location using Place picker google API in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I want to save user form information with location field. For location I want to open google map on some button click and location to be selected when user click on location over map and post-filled location into form.

I found place picker as related solution, So
I have used Place Picker Google API and  I am able to open google map, when I move arrow over preferred location and click on **Select this location (Appearing black color with now coordinates showing under that)**.

Confirmation box opens with 2 option :

1.) Change location
2.) Select **(Disabled mode)**

I want to select anonymous location and return to main activity.

Below is my code :

```
private TextView get_place;
int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST    =   1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    get_place   =   (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    get_place.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder   =   new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
            Intent intent;
            try {
                intent  =   builder.build(getApplicationContext());
                startActivityForResult(intent,PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST );
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode , int resultCode , Intent data ){
    if( requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Place place =   PlacePicker.getPlace(data,this);
            Double latitude = place.getLatLng().latitude;
            Double longitude = place.getLatLng().longitude;
            String address = String.valueOf(latitude)+String.valueOf(longitude);
            get_place.setText(address);
        }
    }
}
```

**Current location coordinates not visible**

[image: Valid XHTML].

**After click on SELECT THIS BUTTON, below window opens with Select button is disabled**

[image: Valid XHTML].

Please let me know, If there is any other best solution.
Code reply will be much helpful or reference link.

Comment: I've got a user with the same problem at the moment so keen to find a solution to this too. What version of Google Play Services is installed?

Comment: I've just replicated this after removing the development (debug) build from my phone and installing from the Play Store. Maybe an API key issue?

Comment: I don't see any error with your code as I checked from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker#add). The SELECT button of the **Use this location?** pop-up dialog was always enabled as stated in this [related SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930796/android-unable-pick-location-from-place-picker). Make sure that your internet connection has no problem.

Comment: @abielita - Internet connection is not the problem in my case. If I deploy to my devices using the debug key everything works as expected. If I deploy using the release key then I get the above behaviour but the maps are displayed fine in other parts of the application.

Comment: I am using following packages -
      **1.)** com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0
      **2.)** com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0
     **3.)** com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3.4

Comment: Have you checked the configuration of the api key in the manifest (see my answer below)?

Comment: Just in case someone finds it useful: you have to insert the `<meta-data>` tag into `<application>`, not into `<manifest>`, otherwise it won't work (although it doesn't throw any build error)

Answer (score 8):

Solution: Enable [Google Places API for Android](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/placesandroid/overview) from dev console.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue (see comments in original post) and it turned out to be caused by a mismatch in the API key entry in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

I'm using Xamarin.Android but the principle should be the same in Java - but your mileage may vary.

Basically my app was using the Maps API and in my manifest I had the API key specified as `com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY` - and everything worked fine. When I implemented the Places Picker i needed to change the key name to `com.google.android.geo.API_KEY` (I did NOT have to change the key itself!). I had done this for the debug configuration but NOT for the release configuration - which still used the Maps key name. Hence building a releasable package was resulting in a manifest which would satisfy the Maps API but not Places.

Changing the release configuration has resolved my issue.

Comment: what did you actually do?how to change release configuration?

Comment: @VikasPandey - as I mentioned I'm using Xamarin and Visual Studio so this may not apply to you. I have a separate GoogleMapsKey.cs file which contains two MetaDataAttributes, one contains my debug api key and the other has the release key. I switch between them with a conditional compilation symbol, e.g. #if DEBUG. You can see an example here: https://github.com/adrianstevens/XamarinAndroidFlyoutMaps/blob/master/ActionBarMap/GoogleMapsKey.cs

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and it got resolved when I enabled Google **Places API for Android** API in my google cloud project.

Comment: Google API for android is enabled

Comment: You have to enable both `Google Maps Android API` and `Google Places API for Android`.

Comment: @LahiruChandima I've enabled both APIs but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

All answers are either old, or irrelevant. I tried 2 solutions, which worked for me.

**Solution 1**

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-contextmanager:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
```

Reference : [googledocumentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

**Solution 2**

1. Google API Console
2. Identify the Android Key the project is using
3. Select Android OS, enter the package name and SHA1
4. Check the google-services.json (from Firebase), it should be using this key.

Rebuild, and everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this

```
  <application>
  ...
  <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
</application>
```

instead of

```
<application>
    <meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
          android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
    <application>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have enabled this API in console.developers.google.com
2. Also (this is was my case) make sure your API key is correct - copy package from gradle applicationId field. Good test will be if you disable restrictions from API key.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if (requestCode==PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST|requestCode==REQUEST_CHECK_SETTING){
           if(resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
               mlocationUpdate = true;
//               startLocationUpdate();
               Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);


               String str_txt = place.getName().toString();
               str_txt += "\n" + place.getAddress().toString();
               placeMarkerOnMap(place.getLatLng());

                mStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
               String mplacename = String.format("%s", place.getName());
               mlatitude = (place.getLatLng().latitude);

               mlongitude = (place.getLatLng().longitude);
               String maddress = String.format("%s", place.getAddress());

               mStringBuilder.append("NAME :");
               mStringBuilder.append(mplacename);
               mStringBuilder.append("\n");

               Log.e("SRC-->",mplacename);
               Log.e("THIS-->",maddress);



               mStringBuilder.append("ADDRESS :");
               mStringBuilder.append(maddress);
             /*mStringBuilder.append("\n");*/
                if (isPickUp==true){
                    edt_pickup.setText(mStringBuilder);

                    isPickUp=false;
                                    }

else if (isDrop==true){
                    edt_drop.setText(mStringBuilder);
                    mlatitudeEnd = (place.getLatLng().latitude);

                    mlongitudeEND = (place.getLatLng().longitude);
                    isDrop=false;
                }

           }}


        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: use the following and make sure you enabled the button which you listen after that u add on--

Answer (score 0):

I also had to enable Geocoding API. These are the APIs that I'm using:

[image]