# Google Place Picker widget not working

Tags: android, google-places-api, android-maps-v2

According to [This Official Post](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker)

I'm following below steps to integrate Place Picker UI dialog with Map.

launcher code

```
    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    startActivityForResult(builder.build(this), PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
```

inside onActivityResult()

```
    if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(this, data);
            tvChooseLocation.setText(place.getName());
        }
    }
```

I have added all permissions & API_KEY in Manifest file

**Problem** is I am not able to select location from Place Picker dialog.

[image: Select button is disabled]

Select button is disabled by default.

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39092825/disable-select-button-while-selecting-location-of-anonymous-location-using-place

Comment: @AndrewR Thanks, but answer still not found.

Comment: Did you solved this problem? I'm getting the same behavior

Comment: @Aks4125 ,Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this so I don't quite know which one of these steps solves it

**In console.developer.google.com**

I enable Places API and Maps API, and download the json from [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin&cnturl=https:%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fidentity%2Fsign-in%2Fandroid%2Fsign-in%3Fconfigured%3Dtrue&cntlbl=Continue%20Adding%20Sign-In).

Also, get the API key from Credential page.

**In Android Studio**

In manifest, add in between `<application> ... </application>`

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="YOUR_KEY_FROM_CREDENTIAL_PAGE"/>
```

In onCreate(), add this (though I don't quite sure this is needed or not)

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
.Builder(this)
.addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
.addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
.enableAutoManage(this, this)
.build();
```

Everything else just follow the tutorial in [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start). Also, I tested it in release version. If you still have the same problem, try make a release one. I failed to get the location in emulator but it work just fine in my phone.

Hopefully this can help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling google places api from google developer console

[Link to console](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/)

--Wanted to comment though but do not have permission.

Comment: @VikasPandey please try out the answer I have posted, if you still got the issue